# Is it possible to get transaction history on a wallet address from inside a smart contract in solidity?

Tags: solidity, tokens

I'm hoping to implement something like this, for even external tokens:

transaction_details(address, token_contract)

which will return the transaction history, i.e. sender, receiver, amount, timestamp...

Is this possible from inside a smart contract?

Comment: I have the same doubt. Did you understand how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's going to be nontrivial, as smart contracts do not have direct access to the transaction history of the blockchain, only to the current state.

With a tool like [Oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it/) you can get data from outside the smart contract ecosystem and use them inside of it. Depending on your use-case however, you probably had better keep this functionality off-chain.

Comment: is there a way with web3js to get transaction history amount from a smart contract?